# Zend Framework: set Module as Subdomain

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

I want to create routes to also get links like:

- my.site.com(/:controller/:action)
- admin.site.com(/:controller/:action)

I tried to add:

```
resources.router.routes.www.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
resources.router.routes.www.route = ":module.nameofmysite.com"
resources.router.routes.www.defaults.module = "default"
resources.router.routes.www.chains.index.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.www.chains.index.route = ":controller/:action/*"
resources.router.routes.www.chains.index.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.www.chains.index.defaults.action = "index"
```

But nothing happens.. (Server not found), how do I fix this?

I've read the zend documentation about this but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: Your setup is correct (you don't have to specify the default values as default-values ;). If the error is "Server not found" this is not a PHP-problem but a server problem. Did you set up the subdomains before?

Comment: @Fge: nope, I installed Zend Server Community Edition and didn't set up any subdomains.

Comment: I don't know the details how the domains are setup there. If I see this correct it uses apache too. So you have to tell apache about the subdomains before. By default it only knows the tld without subdomains.

Comment: I posted my settings from Apache and Hosts.. Strangely.. the non-subdomain routes do work, but the subdomain routes do not work.

Comment: Try to add a ServerAlias *.local to your VirtualHost directive. Currently your VirtualHost isn't configured for any subdomain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem using wildcard subdomains on a local enviroment. I was sure of my routing however the hosts file didin't contain the subdomain. This worked for me

```
127.0.0.1  mydomain.local
127.0.0.1  subdomain.mydomain.local
```